Does a convex quadratic program have a unique dual solution?
As shown in Does a convex quadratic program have a unique solution?, a convex quadratic program has a unique primal solution $x$ if $Q$ is PD.
$$\min \; x^T Q x \\ s.t. \ Ax= b : \lambda \\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ Cx\le d : \mu $$
Is the optimal dual solution for $\lambda$ and $\mu$ unique? Easy to prove?

Uniqueness of Lagrange multipliers ($\lambda$,$\mu$) depends on the characterisques of the problem. If an optimization problem is strictly convex and satisfies certain constraint qualifications, e.g. Slater's, then strong duality holds and the solutions to the primal and dual problems exist. In this case, both solutions are equal and unique. Uniqueness arises from strict convexity.
Remember that a function $f$ is convex if it satisfies the following:
$$ f(\alpha x + (1 - \alpha) y) \leq \alpha  f(x) + (1 - \alpha)f(y),$$
where $x,y \in \text{dom}f$ and $\alpha \in (0,1)$. A function is strictly convex if the above holds with strict inequality. Strict convexity is a property that indicates that the function is not only convex but that it also has positive curvature (a linear function is convex but not strictly convex).
To summarize, the combination of strict convexity and constraint qualifications underpins the uniqueness of Lagrange multipliers in convex optimization.
